# Shared variables between subclasses

Tags: swift, class

I have a main class named `Generator`, which holds working variables for all the classes inside of it. Instantiating other classes from it like so:

```swift
class Generator {
    var registers = [String]()

    class Variable {
        let name: String
        let value: String

        init(name: String, value: String) {
            self.name = name
            self.value = value
        }

        func generate() -> [String] {
            // does something based on parent's `registers`
            return [ /* generated array */ ]
        }
    }

    class Mutate {
        let variable: Generator.Variable
        let actions: [Action]

        init(variable: Generator.Variable, actions: [Action]) {
            self.variable = variable
            self.actions = actions
        }

        func generate() -> [String] {
            // does something based on parent's `registers`
            return [ /* generated array */ ]
        }
    }
}

let generator = Generator()

// block that generates the classes based on user input
let example = generator.Variable( ... )
generator.Variable( ... )
generator.Mutate( ... )
// end

example.generate()
```

What is a good way of doing this when having multiple subclasses? Instead of all the subclasses having a `generator` attribute, can these classes have that "by default"?

Comment: If Generator is a factory class you shouldn't need to have a reference from the child classes to it. Could you explain how you want to use Context here and why it needs a reference to Generator? Maybe there is a better design depending on what your goal is.

Comment: I have modified the question with the full example. Thanks!

Comment: `generator.Variable( ... )` isn't possible. Perhaps you mean `Generator.Variable( ... )`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you must subclass Generator :

```
class Generator {
    var registers = [String]()
    required func generate() -> [String] {
        print("Generator not implemented")
        return []
    }


class Variable : Generator {
    let name: String
    let value: String

    init(name: String, value: String) {
        super.init()
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }

    required func generate() -> [String] {
        // does something based on parent's `registers`
        return [ /* generated array */ ]
    }
}

class Mutate : Variable {
    let actions: [Action]

    init(variable: Variable, actions: [Action] {
        super.init(name: variable.name, value: variable.value)
        self.actions = actions
    }

    required func generate() -> [String] {
        // does something based on parent's `registers`
        return [ /* generated array */ ]
    }
}

// or
class Mutate : Generator {
    let variable : Variable
    let actions: [Action]

    init(variable: Variable, actions: [Action] {
        super.init()
        self.variable =self.actions = actions
    }

    func generate() -> [String] {
        // does something based on parent's `registers`
        return [ /* generated array */ ]
    }
}

let actionArray : [Actions] = [...]
let variable = Variable((name: "var", value: "value"))
let mutate = Mutate(variable: variable, actions: actionArray)
let mutated = mutate.generate()
```

Comment: As a clarification, `registers` is shared between the subclasses and the `generate` method is mutating that variable. Is this some form of inheritance?

Comment: When you subclass each class inherits parent properties and can modify it (this behaviour is the default). Here I put required so that the generate method MUST be overridden in subclass. If not in this the default generate method would be inherited. So that is inheritance.

Comment: Ultimately I need to have the variable be modified on all classes. If a class mutates the variable, does the other class also see the change in its variable?

Comment: A class is a representation of some data structure. A variable declared with one class type, can use property declared in the class type or in any parent class. Be careful when you says other class when speaking of instance. You may need to read a little about classes and instance in swift documentation to help you understand the difference between this terms.